# Using listview with multiple layouts

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I know that the methods like:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
// Define a way to determine which layout to use, here it's just evens and odds.
return position % 2;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
return 2; // Count of different layouts
}
```

are helpful when we want to use multiple layouts with a single adapter.
But these mehtods determine the layout to use according to the "position" of row in listview. But, in my case, the layout to be used is dependent on the type of data to be shown in the row. So, with row position I cant come to know which layout to use. 
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type (or another check) inside your objects in the adapter.
Something like:

```
protected static final int TYPE_ROW = 0;
protected static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position).isHeader())
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    return TYPE_ROW;
}
```

Then you can use it in the getView() method for example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyRow item = getItem(position);
    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(position);
     switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            //
            break;
        case TYPE_ROW:
           //
           break;
    }
    ///....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! here I found the solution. I just need to use my datastructure to find the correct row.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

//we have an image so we are using an ImageRow
if (animals.get(position).getImageId() != null) return 0;

//we don't have an image so we are using a Description Row
else return 1;
}
```